# Что означает имяКласса.new Класс();

Tags: java

Я знаю что `new` используется для создания объекта, но что происходит, когда пишут `имяКласса.new Класс();` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В принципе, тоже для для создания экземпляра, но уже внутренних не статичных классов. Пример:

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner { 
        public void foo() { ... } 
    }
}
```

Здесь класс `Inner` является внутренним для класса `Outer`. В итоге, например, чтобы вызвать метод `foo` у внутреннего класса, можно написать так:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
outer.new Inner().foo();
```

или даже

```
new Outer().new Inner().foo();
```

Но в целом `Class.new Class` это создание экземпляра внутреннего класса "на лету".

---

> А если внутренний класс статический, то в этом случае как его вызывать

Получается так:

```
public class Outer {
    public static class Inner {
        public void foo() { 
            System.out.println("Foo"); 
        }
    }
}

new Outer.Inner().foo();
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял. А если внутренний класс статический, то в этом случае как его вызывать?

Comment: @Альберт добавил пример в конец ответа

Comment: теперь понял, огромное спасибо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В последнем примере вы забыли скобочки после `Inner`. Думаю, вы имели ввиду это: `new Outer.Inner().foo();` Текущий пример будет работать корректно, только если метод `foo()` статический, коего не наблюдается

Comment: @Стас да подправил `new Outer.Inner().foo()` А метод может быть и не статическим

Comment: @АлексейШиманский *Текущий пример будет работать корректно, только если метод foo() статический, коего не наблюдается* - я имел в виду вариант без этих скобок: `Outer.Inner.foo();`